# Error in console - can't use amp-facebook

Tags: amp-html

Everytime I try to create an  (or twitter) in local and I receive this error in the console :

```
Powered by AMP ⚡ HTML – Version 1467308799816
Uncaught Error: Parent origin mismatch: null, file://
```

I copy pasted the code found at [ampbyexample](https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-facebook/) and all I've got is this error with an empty page.

[Here's my code if you need](http://pastebin.com/GVmrxu77)

How do I fix this so the page loads up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you just try to drag and drop the HTML file into the browser? I did that and got the same error but then when I put it into my MAMP htdocs folder, it loaded perfectly fine with no errors from `localhost:<Apache port>/<path to file>`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I'll go and try to figure that out since I did just open it as a normal html page.

Edit : I added it to my iis and I get parser errors instead.

Comment: What errors are you getting from IIS? Haven't touched IIS for a long time now but I might be able to help with that.

Comment: "-" is not valid at the start of a code block.  Only identifiers, keywords, comments, "(" and "{" are valid.

This error is at the line of <style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start ...

I'm not really sure what to do change from there, since it's the required code to run amp.

Comment: I figured it out. I added my file directly into my localhost. It works now! I don't know for the server because of the error parser, but that helped me out. Thank you for your awnser!

Answer (score 0):

The following:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html amp>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="canonical" href="https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-facebook/">
  <script async custom-element="amp-facebook" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-facebook-0.1.js"></script>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1">
  <style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}</style><noscript><style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none}</style></noscript>
    <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>
<amp-facebook width="552"
      height="303"
      layout="responsive"
      data-href="https://www.facebook.com/zuck/posts/10102593740125791">
  </amp-facebook>
  <amp-facebook width="552"
      height="310"
      layout="responsive"
      data-href="https://www.facebook.com/zuck/videos/10102509264909801/">
  </amp-facebook>
  <amp-facebook width="552"
      height="310"
      layout="responsive"
      data-embed-as="video"
      data-href="https://www.facebook.com/zuck/videos/10102509264909801/">
  </amp-facebook>
  </body>
</html>
```

displays this:

[image]

and this:

[image]

Comment: This is exaclty what I had to the difference of <html amp> . Sadly it doesn't work and I'm not sure why yet